# Dagger 2 Android how to pass value on runtime?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

So i've been learning Dagger 2 Android but i am having problem. I want to pass value on runtime. I've read a lot of blogs etc. but couldn't find any solution. Every dagger source is about Dagger 2 not Dagger 2 Android. Is there anyway to do it on Dagger 2 Android too or should i simply move to Dagger 2?

This is AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
                ActivityBuildersModule.class,
                AppModule.class,
        }
)
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

This is ActivityBuildersModule.java

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {
    //For injection class
    @AuthScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
            modules = {
                    AuthModule.class,
                    InjectFragmentBuildersModule.class, //Only gonna exist on AuthActivity Scope
                    MainViewModelsModule.class,
            })
    abstract AuthActivity contributeAuthActivity();
}
```

This is AuthModule.java

```
@Module
public class AuthModule {
    //SubComponent
    @AuthScope
    @Provides
    static Tiers getTiers(){
        return new Tiers();
    }

    @AuthScope
    @Provides
    static Engine getEngine(){
        return new Engine();
    }

    @AuthScope
    @Provides
    static Car getCar(Tiers tiers, Engine engine, @Named("String1")String string){
        return new Car(tiers,engine,string);
    }

    @AuthScope
    @Provides
    static FragmentManager getFragmentManager(AuthActivity authActivity){
        return authActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

And lastly AuthActivity.java

```
public class AuthActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AuthActivity";

    @Inject
    Car car;

    @Inject
    @Named("String1")
    String test1;

    @Inject
    @Named("String2")
    String test2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        car.startCar();
        car.setmBrand("new test brand");
        NavController navController= Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        navController.navigate(R.id.injectFragment);
    }

}
```

So lets say i want to pass some string to Car instead of @Named("String1") how can i do it? I solved the problem with setters but i can't solve that problem like that everytime.